# Proof $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove that if $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\left(a_n \neq 0\right) $, then $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = 0 $, is my proof correct?

Proof:

$ \Rightarrow $:

Let $ a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and suppose that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}(a_n \neq 0) $.

Given $ \epsilon \gt 0 $, There exists $ N_1 $ such that for all $ n > N_1 $, $ a_n \gt \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. There exists $ M $ such that for all $ n \gt M $, $ a_n > 0 $. Choose $ N = max\{N_1, M\} $. For all $ n > N $, $ \left|\frac{1}{a_n}\right| \lt \epsilon$, and hence, $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow 0 $.

$ \Leftarrow $:

Let $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $ and suppose that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}(a_n \gt 0) $.

Given $ M \gt 0 $, There exists $ N $ such that for all $ n \gt N $, $ \left|a_n\right| \lt \frac{1}{M} $. Therefore, for all $ n \gt N $, $ \frac{1}{a_n} \gt M $, and hence, $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty $.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: The converse implication is not valid. Set $a_n=(-1)^n n$. Then $\frac{1}{a_n}\to 0$ but $a_n\not\to+\infty$ and $a_n\not\to-\infty$. If you are doing real analysis, how do you define convergence to "infinity" without specifying whether positive or negative infinity? Or, is the restriction that $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: It is a good habit to always write the infinity symbol along with its sign $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.